# Find a better logic to remove duplicated code from two different methods

Tags: php

I have to update a class property with the method name and then call a method that executes some code based on this property. The code is the same in both methods, but I am not seeing a way to remove this code duplication. I am trying to avoid using a parameter.

```
public function register(){
    $this->operation = __FUNCTION__;
    $this->handleOperation();
}

public function unregister(){
    $this->operation = __FUNCTION__;
    $this->handleOperation();
}
```

**Update 1**

As [Yoda](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/40964/yoda) suggested, here is a more complete code. It is a class to manipulate multiple functions for PHP autoloading. Now I am using parameters in `handleOperation()`. Example of use:

```
$Autoloader = new Autoloader();
$Autoloader->setFunctions(array('controllers', 'commons'));
$Autoloader->setModule('default');
$Autoloader->register();
```

Class code:

```
class Autoloader {

    private $functions_to_handle = array();
    private $module;
    private $function;
    private $paths = array();

    public function setFunctions($functions){
        $this->functions_to_handle = is_array($functions) ? $functions : array($functions);
    }

    public function setModule($module){
        $this->module = $module;
    }

    public function register(){
        $this->handleOperation(__FUNCTION__);
    }

    public function unregister(){
        $this->handleOperation(__FUNCTION__);
    }

    private function handleOperation($operation){
        $built_in_function = $this->mountBuiltInFunctionName($operation);

        foreach($this->functions_to_handle as $function){
            $built_in_function(array($this, $function));
        }
    }

    private function mountBuiltInFunctionName($operation){
        return 'spl_autoload_' . $operation;
    }

    private function controllers($classe) {
        $this->function = __FUNCTION__;

        $this->refreshPaths($classe);
        $this->loadClass();
    }

    private function commons($classe) {
        $this->function = __FUNCTION__;

        $this->refreshPaths($classe);
        $this->loadClass();
    }

    private function refreshPaths($classe){
        switch ($this->function) {

            case 'commons' :
                $this->paths = array(
                    '/usr/share/evokernel/core/common/' . $classe . '.php',
                );
            break;

            case 'controllers':
                $this->paths = array(
                    'core/controllers/' . $classe . '.php',
                    'modules/' . $this->module . '/controllers/' . $classe . '.php',
                    'shared/modules/' . $this->module . '/controllers/' . $classe . '.php'
                );
            break;

            default:
                throw new Exception('Invalid function: ' . $this->function);
        }
    }

    private function loadClass(){
        foreach ($this->paths as $path) {
            if (is_file($path)) {
                require_once($path);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying not to use a parameter ?

Comment: @konijn, I read recently "Clean Code" by Robert Martin, there he discourages to use parameters, so i am trying to follow this recommendation when possible.

Comment: That sounds so wrong ;)

Comment: @konijn, I didn't agree completly with this, but i am trying to see the benefits. Do you have a suggestion with parameters?

Comment: Too many parameters is a bad thing, but even in Uncle Bob's own "clean" examples, some functions have parameters.  I think it is good to avoid using parameters that make the code less readable and understandable, but also advisable to use a parameter (or two, or even three) when the alternative is worse.

Comment: This looks more like bad class design, we could probably help you better if you could post whole class here.

Comment: @Yoda, I inserted more code, please take a look

Comment: @konijn, I putted more code, please take a look

Comment: @DavidK, There is more code now, please take a look

Comment: @MarcioSimao Are you building some kind of framework?

Comment: Other than swapping out `__FUNCTION__` in favor of `"register"` and `"unregister"`, I don't see a problem *with these three specific methods* (including `handleOperation`).

Comment: @Yoda, Yes, we are building a micro framework, it will fit better in our system requirements. We had some problems with our old autoloader because now we are using PHP [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

Comment: @MarcioSimao In my opinion duplicating code in this case is alright and is preferable over use of parameters. In the class there is one pretty obvious thing and that is use of Exception. You should rather create something like `class AutoloaderException extends Exception { ... }` and then use it instead of `Exception`. Using just `Exception` is too wide in this case.

Comment: I also think the duplication is OK in this amount. Basically you have two functions that must do the same thing, and you do it by writing the same (single) line of code inside each function. It is hard to imagine a much clearer or more concise way of expressing that idea.

Comment: @DavidK, Do you preffer with or without parameters?

Comment: Do you mean the register() and unregister() functions? To me, the two-line versions say, "Here is an operation you might perform if I ask you to (that's the first line); OK, now perform the operation I told you about before (second line)." Using a parameter, you do have to understand how the parameter relates to the method, but it seems obvious enough in this case. Without the parameter, you not only have to understand how the property relates to the method, you have to understand these two lines aren't doing two independent things, which in my view makes this more complicated.

Comment: Short answer: I liked the one-parameter version better.

Comment: @DavidK, I think the same, i am going to use the one-parameter version. Thanks for your colaboration!

Answer (score 2):

Short version: **Use a parameter!**

```
public function handleOperation($action) {}
public function register() { $this->handleOperation("register"); }
public function unregister() { $this->handleOperation("unregister"); }
```

---

Slightly longer version: **Don't be a smartass**

You don't need to dynamically call `spl_autoload_$function`, it's pointless and unreadable. Just call `spl_autoload_register`and `spl_autoload_unregister`when you need it. It's unlikely for the function names to change.